# Implementing SwipeView, SwipeRefreshlayout, and Navigation Drawer in one activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

as the title suggests, I'm trying to implement all of these features at once. Originally I had a fully functioning side-nav with a SwipeRefreshLayout which holds a list view (using a custom list adapter). I then added a ViewPager inside of the SwipeRefreshLayout, and everything mostly works…except that as I swipe the list view does not appear in the new 'tabs' sometimes. Most of the time I see the first page and list view, I swipe right, nothing, I swipe right, nothing, I swipe **left**, list view, I swipe to the beginning, nothing.

I should add that everything is entirely dynamic, the navigation items are received from my server (which is also the number of pages) and each page has a custom list adapter with different list items. All of this dynamic information seems to be received and adapted correctly per page swipe etc.

Now for the code!

Drawer layout with swiperefreshlayout and view pager embedded. "drawer.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"> 

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
   android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
     <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        />


    <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. A solid background is used for contrast
         with the content view. -->
     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/grey_lighter"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Listview which holds the custom list items created dynamically in the activity "dashboard.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/LV_dashboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" >

    </ListView>
```

Now for the fragment activity :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mContext = this.getApplicationContext();
        navItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.setContentView(R.layout.drawer); 
        mMerchantIds = Session.get().getMerchID(); //array retrieved from cache used for api

        mCustomerPagerAdapter = new CustomerPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


        // Set up the ViewPager, attaching the adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mCustomerPagerAdapter);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        mNavTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_array); //I realize this isn't dynamic, I haven't gotten around to that just yet.

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        connection = new WiselyRequest();

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.nav_item, mNavTitles));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
                ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }    
    }
```

This branches off into two parts, we'll start with the Drawer:

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectItem(position);
            }
        }

        private void selectItem(int position) {
            // update the main content by replacing fragments (this is not what the pager does)
            Fragment fragment = null;

            fragment = new CustomerFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(KEY_MERCHANT_ID, (mMerchantIds.get(position)));
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();


            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);

            setTitle(mNavTitles[position]);



            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

        }
```

Here is the view pager:

```
public class CustomerPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

            public CustomerPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                super(fm);
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int i) {
                Fragment fragment = new CustomerFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                Log.d("Wisely", "merchants: "+mMerchantIds.get(i));
                args.putString(KEY_MERCHANT_ID, (mMerchantIds.get(i))); // Our object is just an integer :-P
                fragment.setArguments(args);
                return fragment;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                // For this contrived example, we have a 100-object collection.
                return mMerchantIds.size(); //equal to the number of merchantss (that many customer objects) 
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                return "OBJECT " + (position + 1);
            }
        }
```

Here is the customer fragment that both the drawer and pager are utilizing and where on refresh is handled:

```
 public class CustomerFragment extends Fragment implements OnRefreshListener {
                private View rootView;
                SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout; 
                public CustomerFragment() {

                }

                @Override
                public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    Bundle args = getArguments();
                    String merchantID = args.getString(KEY_MERCHANT_ID);
                    if(connection.checkConnectivity(getApplicationContext())){
                        getRecentCustomers(API.getRecentCustomers()+"?merchant_id="+merchantID); //api call works totally fine, and correctly sets up the adapter
                    }
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(DashboardActivity.this, "Need to be connected to the internet!", 4000).show();
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard, container, false);//inflates the dashboard
                    swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
                    swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
                     swipeLayout.setColorScheme(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright, android.R.color.holo_green_light, android.R.color.holo_orange_light, android.R.color.holo_red_light);
                    registerClickCallback(rootView);

                    return rootView;    
                }

                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                    if(connection.checkConnectivity(getApplicationContext()))
                        reloadActivity(); //literally turns the activity on and off without animation
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(DashboardActivity.this, "Need to be connected to the internet!", 4000).show();
                }
```

I believe the issue exits in my layouts, not in the list adapter or customer fragment which seem to be working fine (every time I swipe to a new page the api is called and the correct data is put into the list view. I just can't see it. Also I realize that the navdrawer is not dynamic, but my bigger issue at the moment is being able to swipe through multiple list views on pages. When I change my customerFragment to inflate a simple text view with a number in it, it seems to work fine, except that the first page never goes away, other pages just pile on top of it (I think this has to do with the framelayout in the drawer but removing it breaks the code because my nag drawer relies on it). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you will have to create your own classes extending DrawerLayout or ViewPager.
Inside of your classes you have to Override methods:

onInterceptTouchEvent() - here you evaluate TouchEvent and return true, if you are intercepting it (not passing to the child View)

You have to tweak the conditions of intercepting based on what you are trying to achieve.

Guide is here:
http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html